# file does not exist in apache error log, though mod_rewrite is on

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

On my live site, the first login screen, I have entered credentials for "username/password".

I have submitted the form without error, it redirects me to login screen.

I have checked in cpanel error log, the error is below:

`[Fri Aug 03 16:18:13 2018] [error] [client IP address] File does not exist: /home/folder/url, referer: url`

I have checked that mod_rewrite is enabled and also `AllowOverride all`.

Is there any other setting required?

My server is Linux with CentOS

Below is my .htaccess file, please let me know if there is anything wrong,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please explain what is it you want to do and which is the problem you are finding. By the way mod_rewrite on its own won't do anything, you need to set the rules to match what you want to rewrite. So also add the rules you have set.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have edited my question for ,htaccess  rules ,please look into it.

Comment: Please explain what is it you want to do and which is the problem you are finding.

Comment: In my cpanel ,it gives me error like ,[Fri Aug 03 16:18:13 2018] [error] [client IP address] File does not exist: /home/folder/url, referer: url

Comment: in my site, I login with username/password then not able to get result in $_POST at php side, while my local system is working fine for this site

Comment: Your question is more related to support with cpanel than to a problem with mod_rewrite, or at least the relation between the two things is not made evident in the question.